# bathtub drain stuck

Tags: bathroom, shower, drain, clog

My bathtub drain is stuck, and I used lots of Drano Clog Remover in the past, but it only lasted for a few days. Also I tried all kinds of Drain Clog Remover Cleaning Tool, and none of them works.

Currently, I want to completely remove the existing bathtub stopper, and install a drain cap that looks like

[image]

However the current drain looks like

[image]

and it looks like there is a metal rob stick out of the drain, and i can't remove it. has anybody had similar issues in the past? thanks for any help.

Comment: can you provide a pic with better lighting, maybe with a flashlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, that center post will unscrew from the center, but that won't help remove the drain.  The drain screws in just like the new one in your picture.  Removing the center bar will allow you to get a drain removal tool in there.

Before trying anything, realize that drains that old usually do not come out in one piece.  The cross bar inside the drain could break when trying to remove the center post, but even if it doesn't, it can then break when trying to unscrew the drain.

Breaking out the center post or just removing it would allow you to put a normal strainer over the drain, and that might be good enough for you. Unless you have access to the under side of the tub to help make a repair, I wouldn't try very hard to remove the drain.

Comment: i removed the center post and put a plastic cover there to catch all hairs